# iOS Touch ID for Web Development

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, touch-id

I am currently trying to figure out a way where I can build a responsive website, however once the website loads on an iOS Device I wanted to use the new iOS Touch ID api to allow members to login. I know it is possible to do such things using Native ofcourse and also Cordova (http://cordova.apache.org/) but I want it to work as an authentication system with nearly any web development code base.

Comment: you can't, the API isn't accessible from the browser

Comment: Hum gotcha, atleast would I be able to perhaps create a native application or a cross platform one and simply send a request from the web browser to this app and see if it returns authentication token and use that?

Comment: @NickGanguly Hi, i am also looking for the similar scenario, so have you got any solution for the same? How have you achieved mapping between website credentials with fingerprints ? Can you please guide

Answer (score 2):

There is a Apache Cordova plugin that gives you a simple [Javascript API](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-touchid). Using it becomes a simple call like this:

```
 touchid.checkSupport(successCallback, notSupportedCallback);
 touchid.authenticate(successCallback, failureCallback, text);
```

Hope that helps