# how to get a persons fingerprint through javascript

Tags: javascript, fingerprint

I need to add a feature where every invoice my asp.net solution needs to be signed digitally by the person making the invoice. So my client wants the option that rather than signing digitally using a mouse, they want the person making the invoice to put in their fingerprint.

How can I get the finger print of a person in my web page using javascript.

Comment: There's a lot of caveats to this question.
First: what are the devices? IE might have access to ActiveX to allow you to access the drivers. But ultimately, the device the users are going to use is going to limit you on this.

Comment: No way this would ever be possible, what a security and privacy nightmare.

Comment: There's a [related q/a regarding iOS Touch ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26760290/ios-touch-id-for-web-development).

Comment: You are probably going to need a combination of technologies. On the front-end side, you will probably need an active-x like control to allow a finger-print reading device to send information to the web browser. From a security-standpoint, I would also take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd984947(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I help people integrate Biometrics Authentication in Web, Cloud and Android. Nowadays you can actually use JavaScript to implement a Web based Biometric Enrollment and Authentication solution that works on Multiple web browsers with either a Windows Server Back-end or a Linux server Back-end like CentOS 7, Ubuntu, Suse, Gentoo etc. Check out JavaScript Biometric Authentication & Integration pack here  https://jomutech.com/javascriptbiometricauthentication/ . It uses web sockets and you can integrate it with either a PHP, ASP.NET, Python, NodeJS, JSP back-end or even Spring Framework for Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is about digitally signing and using JavaScript to do this.

I think accessing finger print scanners may not be possible, many devices simply don't have finger print scanners let alone have access to them via JavaScript.

What I would suggest instead is looking at what JavaScript makes available and how useful this is as digital signing.  For our work we just required that the user type in their name (and displayed it in a fancy handwriting font) and that was enough.  But you could do better than this by accessing the web cam or mike via JavaScript.  You could then get either...

1. A voice print (user states their name and it is recorded)
2. A photo/image of the user (via webcam)
3. A photo/image of users finger (for finger print)

The above methods have a number of draw backs, the main one being you can't validate that the user was actually in the photo (they could hold up a magazine image in front of the webcam) but this is true of many signing methods (written signature on paper can be anything).

If you wanted to go down the finger print route you could then process the image (from the web cam) of a finger print, although this would be fairly complex.

Comment: The answer is outdated. There is a spec being worked on: https://github.com/w3c/webauthn