# Way to access fingerprint in iOS mobile using javascript

Tags: javascript, biometrics

Is there any JavaScript API to access fingerprint in iOS mobile?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26760290/ios-touch-id-for-web-development

Comment: google: ios fingerprint javascript